# Ignore Inherited Property EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

TB_R_LEAVE_Configuration

```
public class TB_R_LEAVE_REQ_ID_Configuration : DataUseLogConfiguration<Entities.TB_R_LEAVE_REQ_ID>
{
    public TB_R_LEAVE_REQ_ID_Configuration()
    {
        ToTable("TB_R_LEAVE_REQ_ID");

        HasKey(e => e.LEAVE_REQ_ID);
        HasRequired<TB_R_LEAVE_REQ>(e => e.TB_R_LEAVE_REQ);            

        Property(e => e.LEAVE_REQ_ID).HasColumnName("LEAVE_REQ_ID").HasMaxLength(10);
        Property(e => e.LEAVE_ID).HasColumnName("LEAVE_ID").HasMaxLength(5);
    }
}
```

DataUseLogConfiguration (abstract base class)

```
public abstract class DataUseLogConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : DataUseLog
{
    public DataUseLogConfiguration()
    {
        Property(e => e.CREATED_BY).HasColumnName("CREATED_BY").HasMaxLength(5).IsRequired();
        Property(e => e.CREATED_DT).HasColumnName("CREATED_DT").IsRequired();
        Property(e => e.UPDATED_BY).HasColumnName("UPDATED_BY").HasMaxLength(5).IsOptional();
        Property(e => e.UPDATED_DT).HasColumnName("UPDATED_DT").IsOptional();
    }
}
```

I want to ignore all DataUseLogConfiguration properties

1. I tried use Ignore on TB_R_LEAVE_Configuration:

   `Ignore(e => e.UPDATED_BY);`

and this happen:

> "The property 'UPDATED_BY' is not a declared property on type
>   'TB_R_LEAVE_REQ_ID'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly
>   excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or
>   NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid
>   primitive property."

2. Without Ignore this happen:

> "ORA-00904: \"Extent2\".\"UPDATED_BY\": invalid identifier"

The Data Model also use inherited base class

```
public class TB_R_LEAVE_REQ_ID : DataUseLog
{
    public string LEAVE_REQ_ID { get; set; }
    public string LEAVE_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual TB_M_LEAVE TB_M_LEAVE { get; set; }
    public virtual TB_R_LEAVE_REQ TB_R_LEAVE_REQ { get; set; }
}
```

How i properly ignore properties on base class just using fluent API on TB_R_LEAVE_Configuration (im try to avoid changing the data model)

Comment: i think that if you map a property to a column and after that you say to ignore that property something could not work properly, and it make sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for everyone who try to help me, btw this is how i solve it with just edit the TB_R_LEAVE_REQ_ID_Configuration

```
public class TB_R_LEAVE_REQ_ID_Configuration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entities.TB_R_LEAVE_REQ_ID>
{
    public TB_R_LEAVE_REQ_ID_Configuration()
    {
        ToTable("TB_R_LEAVE_REQ_ID");

        HasKey(e => e.LEAVE_REQ_ID);
        HasRequired<TB_R_LEAVE_REQ>(e => e.TB_R_LEAVE_REQ);

        Ignore(e => e.UPDATED_BY);
        Ignore(e => e.UPDATED_DT);
        Ignore(e => e.CREATED_BY);
        Ignore(e => e.CREATED_DT);

        Property(e => e.LEAVE_REQ_ID).HasColumnName("LEAVE_REQ_ID").HasMaxLength(10);
        Property(e => e.LEAVE_ID).HasColumnName("LEAVE_ID").HasMaxLength(5);
    }
}
```

notice that i changed the inheritance to EntityTypeConfiguration then just add the ignores as usual

Hope this help everyone in the future